# How to read result of `/api-docs` swagger endioint?

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have quite an old application. Spring 5(non-boot). I wanted to have a swagger to understand contract between FE and BE.
I think I've read all topics at SO why Swagger-ui could be unavailable but it still doesn't fully working. But I was able to make `/api-docs` endpoint working altough I want to make working `/swagger-ui/index.htm`. I have no idea how to configure it so I want to know how to read such a hige json which is a respinse of `/api-docs`. Looks like it already contains all contracts.
I tried to find online services like https://api-docs.io/ but it can't read the result for some reasons. Are there any other tools to read that response ?

Comment: There are 2 parts to an OpenAPI/Swagger - you need the specification document, that's  `/api-docs` and is generated by `springfox-swagger2`. The 2nd part is a UI that can display that document. That's usually `springfox-swagger-ui` if you include it on the server itself, alternatively if your docs at `/api-docs` are public you can simply put the url in the top of https://petstore.swagger.io/ and look at them there. https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api has some config hints for non boot apps but your question doesn't contain any clues why it may not work for you

Comment: @zapl thank you for your comment. 
SO is full of different questions/asnswers about reason why swagger doesn't work. 

I tried at least

1.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722686/2674303 
2.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258645/2674303 
3.  https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/776 
4.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545893/2674303 
...

But I had almost no luck for some reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If swagger generated OpenAPI document in YAML or JSON formats then you can copy and paste them here for a nice UI: https://editor.swagger.io

Comment: Yes, it renders something but also it complains for a long list of errors:
[link](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2022/11/08/0005/3037/338909/09/cd470d6676.jpg)